# MongoDB cluster Shard connection string suddenly misconfigured

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

A few hours ago, we had an outage in a server which was running a `mongos` instance. After resolving the underlying issue, the `mongos` has been unable to boot with the following error:

```
"ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"Invariant failure","attr":{"expr":"!groupAndId.groupData","file":"src/mongo/s/sharding_task_executor_pool_controller.cpp","line":134}
"ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"\n\n***aborting after invariant() failure\n\n"
"ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"}
```

And now, other `mongos` and `mongod` instances that required restarts are not able to boot up as well with the same error - so in time they might all fail one by one and not be able to boot again.

Our MongoDB cluster contains 5 data shards and 1 config shard, each consisting of a 3 member replica set. Let's label each data shard A,B,C,D,E, and each instance A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,etc...

Upon closer inspection of the failing `mongos` instance, I noticed some odd things in the RSM Topology Change logs. The hosts seems to be mixed up between the replset. Notice the topology change for replset-B, containing 1 host from its set, but the hosts for other sets, but at the same time, the "setName" property showing replset-A.

```
"ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor",
"msg":"RSM Topology Change",
"attr":{
  "replicaSet":"replset-B",
  "newTopologyDescription":"{ 
    id: \"bfcaaf31-9ead-497b-85b9-1e98dbf97805\", 
    topologyType: \"ReplicaSetNoPrimary\", 
    servers: { 
      server-B1:27017: { 
        address: \"server-B1:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", 
        minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, 
        lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), 
        hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} 
      }, 
      server-A1:27017: { 
        address: \"server-A1:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", 
        minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, 
        lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), 
        hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} 
      }, 
      server-A2:27017: { 
        address: \"server-A2:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", 
        minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, 
        lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), 
        hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} 
      }, 
      server-A3:27017: { 
        address: \"server-A3:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", 
        minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, 
        lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), 
        hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} 
      } 
    }, 
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30, 
    setName: \"replset-A\", 
    compatible: true 
  }",
  "previousTopologyDescription":"{ 
    id: \"2e9451c0-f13e-4d77-b9f9-6900ee5754ab\", 
    topologyType: \"Unknown\", 
    servers: { 
      server-B2:27017: { 
        address: \"server-B2:27017\", type: \"Unknown\", 
        minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, 
        lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), 
        hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} 
      }, 
      server-B3:27017: { 
        address: \"server-B3:37017\", type: \"Unknown\", 
        minWireVersion: 0, maxWireVersion: 0, 
        lastUpdateTime: new Date(-9223372036854775808), 
        hosts: {}, arbiters: {}, passives: {} 
      } 
    }, 
    compatible: true 
  }"
}
```

I ran `sh.status()` on a functioning `mongos` instance, and lo and behold, the `shard-B` was appearing as `replset-B/server-A1:27017,server-A2:27017,server-A3:27017`. I have no idea how this happened. We've had this cluster running for a couple of years now, and the last change to the topology was adding shard-E a couple of weeks ago. All the `mongod.conf` have the correct replSet names in them, doing `rs.conf()` and `rs.status()` on the primaries of each replica set shows no inconsistencies.

I've even tried updating the `config.shards` collection directly and `$set`ting the correct hosts for the problematic shard's, both through `mongos` and through the config primary, but not only did it not work (the other `mongos` instances kept failing with the same error), but it reverted back to the old (wrong) connection string after a while (which I suspect has to do with the `ShardRegistry` mechanism that updates the `config.shards` as well).

Running `db.runCommand({getShardMap: 1})` gives me the following result (which I suspect is another symptom of some conflict somewhere):

```
"connStrings" : {
  ...all good until...
  "replset-B/server-A1:27017,server-A2:27017,server-A3:27017" : "shard-B",
}
```

I'm nearing my wit's end. Downtime is not really an option, and I was wondering if someone more knowledgeable in the inner workings of MongoDB had some insight to share on this.

Comment: "updating the config.shards collection directly" would be quite risky, I think. You should not do that unless you are advised by Mongo support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. The issue was a DNS configuration - the hostname mapping for one of the B servers was pointing to the IP address of an A server. Somehow this took a while to manifest itself.